# Frank - Wolfe Algorithm in matlab

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to solve the following question :

```
  maximize  x^2-5x+y^2-3y  

 x+y <=  8 
 x<=2  
 x,y>= 0
```

By using Frank Wolf algorithm ( according to http://web.mit.edu/15.053/www/AMP-Chapter-13.pdf ).

But after running of the following program:

```
    syms x y t;

    f = x^2-5*x+y^2-3*y; 

    fdx = diff(f,1,x); % f'x
    fdy = diff(f,1,y); % y'x

    x0 = [0 0];      %initial point

    A = [1 1;1 0];    %constrains matrix
    b = [8;2];   
    lb = zeros(1,2); 



    eps = 0.00001; 
    i = 1;
    X = [inf inf];
    Z = zeros(2,200); %result for end points (x1,x2) 

    rr = zeros(1,200);
    options = optimset('Display','none');

    while( all(abs(X-x0)>[eps,eps]) && i < 200)

        %f'x(x0) 
        c1 = subs(fdx,x,x0(1));
        c1 = subs(c1,y,x0(2));

        %f'y(x0) 
        c2 = subs(fdy,x,x0(1));
        c2 = subs(c2,y,x0(2));

        %optimization point of linear taylor function
        ys = linprog((-[c1;c2]),A,b,[],[],lb,[],[],options); 


        %parametric representation of line
        xt = (1-t)*x0(1)+t*ys(1,1);
        yt = (1-t)*x0(2)+t*ys(2,1);

        %f(x=xt,y=yt)
        ft = subs(f,x,xt);
        ft = subs(ft,y,yt);

        %f't(x=xt,y=yt)
        ftd = diff(ft,t,1);

         %f't(x=xt,y=yt)=0 -> for max point 
        [t1] = solve(ftd); % (t==theta)


        X = double(x0);%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

        %  [ xt(t=t1)  yt(t=t1)]
        xnext(1) = subs(xt,t,t1) ;
        xnext(2) =  subs(yt,t,t1) ;

        x0 = double(xnext);
        Z(1,i) = x0(1);
        Z(2,i) = x0(2);


        i = i + 1;
    end





    x_point = Z(1,:);
    y_point = Z(2,:);



% Draw result
scatter(x_point,y_point);
hold on;

% Print results
fprintf('The answer is:\n');

fprintf('x = %.3f \n',x0(1));
fprintf('y = %.3f \n',x0(2));


res = x0(1)^2 - 5*x0(1) + x0(2)^2 - 3*x0(2);
fprintf('f(x0) = %.3f\n',res);
```

I get the following result:

```
    x = 3.020 
    y = 0.571 
    f(x0) = -7.367
```

And this no matter how many iterations I running this program (1,50 or 200).

Even if I choose a different starting point (For example, x0=(1,6) ), I get a negative answer to most.

I know that is an approximation, but the result should be positive (for x0 final, in this case).

**My question is : what's wrong with my implementation?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what equation are you implementing? (the equations in the pdf have numbers in parenthesis, which on eare you using). I ran your code and saw it finishes when `i=4` i think you mad an error here. before the loop you said `i=1` that should be `i_max=1` then in your loop instead of saying `&& i <100` say `&& i < i_max`

Comment: I meant i<200. Correct  after 4 iterations the while finished(but if I'm trying to solve the minimize (ie [c1;c2]), this is working perfectly).

Answer (score 1):

i changed a few things, it still doesn't look right but hopefully this is getting you in the right direction. It looks like the intial x0 points make a difference to how the algorithm converges.

Also make sure to check what `i` is after running the program, to determine if it ran to completion or exceeded the maximum iterations

```
lb = zeros(1,2); 
ub = [2,8]; %if x+y<=8 and x,y>0 than both x,y < 8



eps = 0.00001; 
i_max = 100;
i = 1;
X = [inf inf];
Z = zeros(2,i_max); %result for end points (x1,x2) 

rr = zeros(1,200);
options = optimset('Display','none');

while( all(abs(X-x0)>[eps,eps]) && i < i_max)

    %f'x(x0) 
    c1 = subs(fdx,x,x0(1));
    c1 = subs(c1,y,x0(2));

    %f'y(x0) 
    c2 = subs(fdy,x,x0(1));
    c2 = subs(c2,y,x0(2));

    %optimization point of linear taylor function
    [ys, ~ , exit_flag] = linprog((-[c1;c2]),A,b,[],[],lb,ub,x0,options);
```

so here is the explanation of the changes

`ub`, uses our upper bound. After i added a ub, the result immediately changed

`x0`, start this iteration from the previous point

`exit_flag` this allows you to check exit_flag after execution (it always seems to be 1 indicating it solved the problem correctly)

Comment: Thanks andrew. This is stop after i=12, and stil I got a negative result from f(x0)  (It can not be).

Comment: The upper bound should be `ub = [2,8];`.

Comment: I changed the UB, good catch. It looks like `linprog` really is minimizing your function though `figure(4);[xv,yv]=meshgrid(0:.05:2,0:.05:8);z = xv.^2-5*xv+yv.^2-3*yv;mesh(xv,yv,z);grid on` even though it should be maximizing. maybe you need to make another sign change besides `-[c1;c2]` but at this point I really am just guessing